# What is the history of "one nation under God"?

Tags: united-states, religion, catholic-church, god

What is the history of the United States motto "one nation under God"?

I saw it claimed in § "History of the " of

- Campbell Phillip. 2019. [*The Story of Civilization : Vol. 4 - the History of the United States One Nation Under God Text Book*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8759). Ashland: TAN Books.

that

> The Knights of Columbus even convinced President Eisenhower to add the words ‘Under God’ to the Pledge of Allegiance.

Is this true?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)How is this not answered by [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pledge_of_Allegiance#Addition_of_%22under_God%22)?

Comment: @MCW Wikipedia isn't reliable. I've added a source where I found a certain claim and I'd like to verify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **I pledge Allegiance to the flag of the United States of America and to the Republic for which it stands, one nation under God, indivisible, with Liberty and Justice for all.**<sup>1</sup>

[The Pledge of Allegiance](https://web.archive.org/web/20220630220518/http://www.wvsd.uscourts.gov/pledge-allegiance) was modified in 1954.

> The last change in language came on Flag Day 1954, when Congress passed a law, which added the words “under God” after “one nation.”

In 1892, Francis Bellamy revised Balch's verse:

> Bellamy's version of the pledge is largely the same as the one formally adopted by Congress 50 years later, in 1942. The official name of The Pledge of Allegiance was adopted in 1945. The most recent alteration of its wording came on Flag Day (June 14) in 1954, when the words "under God" were added.

It's first version was written in [1885 by Captain George Thatcher Balch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pledge_of_Allegiance).

---

**After the question was updated, it seems important to widen the sources and reasons *why* the words "*under god*" were added**.

On September 17, 2002, the [107th Congress](https://www.congress.gov/congressional-report/107th-congress/house-report/659/1):

> Clearly, America has a rich history of referring to God in its political and civic discourse and acknowledging the important role faith and religion have played throughout our Nation's history.

According to [*History*](https://www.history.com/news/pledge-allegiance-under-god-schools):

> The push to add “under God” to the pledge gained momentum during the second Red Scare, a period when U.S. politicians were keen to assert the moral superiority of U.S. capitalism over Soviet communism, which many conservatives regarded as “godless.”

[Britannica's ProCon](https://undergod.procon.org/historical-timeline/) shows a timeline with related events, and it seems like, when started, the snowball effect only grew bigger:

> Feb. 12, 1948 - Sons of the American Revolution Chaplain Includes 'under God' in Pledge Recitation.
>
> Apr. 22, 1951 - Knights of Columbus Add 'Under God' to Pledge Recited at Meetings.
>
> 1952-1954 - Hearst Campaigns to Add 'Under God' to Pledge.
>
> 1953 - House and Senate Introduce Bills to Add 'Under God' to Pledge.

---

<sup>1. every step and its meaning are explained in the link [*The Pledge of Allegiance*](https://web.archive.org/web/20220630220518/http://www.wvsd.uscourts.gov/pledge-allegiance)</sup>

Comment: Wow, so it's a relatively recent addition.

Comment: @Geremia - IIRC, the *reason* it was added then was because the Cold War was heating up (this was smack dab in the middle of the Red Scare). The "God" stuff was deemed a poison pill to Communists, as they were officially atheist, and thus could no longer honestly take the pledge. So it was really an **anti-Communist** measure more than a pro-Religion measure.

Comment: @T.E.D. It's both.

Comment: @Geremia - Disagree. This country had nearly a century before then to add that, including more religous periods like [The Third Great Awakening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Great_Awakening) which was going on while the pledge was written. Instead, it was added during the height of the Red Scare.

Comment: @T.E.D. The Great Awakening was primarily Protestant. If the quote in my edited question is true, Catholics were responsible for adding "under God" to the pledge.

Comment: @Geremia - I'd point out that's an explicitly Catholic source. It looks like the Knights of Columbus (a Catholic social organization) did [initiate a campaign](https://www.kofc.org/en/who-we-are/our-history/one-nation-under-god.html#:~:text=The%20Knights%20of%20Columbus%20initiated,under%20God%E2%80%9D%20to%20the%20pledge.) to add it in 1951, and it isn't tough to find them taking credit for its passage. What's a bit tougher is finding non-Catholic sources agreeing with them.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, I'm wondering what the non-Catholic sources say.